# Why does low DC gain move an integrator pole?

Tags: buck, control

[image]

[image]

[image]

The author is describing a voltage-mode buck control loop. In particular, he is describing PI compensation. The line I have highlighted is where he mentions 'In the simulation results, the dominant pole contributed by the integrator is not at the origin because a non-ideal EA has a limited low-frequency gain.'

I don't understand. **Why is the pole of the integrator no longer at the origin because of limited low-freq gain of another stage??**

Comment: Simple answer: Pole at the origin means "infinite DC gain". When the DC gain is not infinite, the pole cannot be at the origin.

Comment: @LvW But there's still an integrator 1/s in the transfer function. A finite DC gain would make that K/s -> still a pole at zero? How does having a finite gain, get rid of the integrator from a mathematical TF point of view?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a little slow, but what does "EA" stand for?

Comment: EA = error amplifier

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an ideal integrator has an infinite gain, it follows that a non-ideal element will have a finite gain, while maintaining the slope. That means the magnitude will be limited by the finite amplification of the EA (error amplifier). If you take a right triangle with the 90° angle at the origin (DC) and you cut the top, you get a trapezoid -- a *finite* pole:

[image: finite pole]

It also means that yo no longer get the \$1/s\$ that you expect, you get a \$1/(ks+1)\$. The low frequency amplification is still tens of dB, but it's no longer infinite.

Comment: It's an ideal integrator and a non-ideal EA. My understanding is that the system should be TF = (K_EA / (s + w_EA) ) * ( 1/s ) where K_EA is the gain of the EA and w_EA is the pole of the EA and 1/s is the added integrator. The pole at s=0 still exists and is not being modified by the presence of an EA with a limited low frequency gain.

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw No, the EA makes the whole transfer function, including the integrator. The fact that you see there a \$1/s\$ that's just the *theoretical* transfer function. You don't see in there any input impedances of the opamp, or the output impedance, or parasitic inductances or capacitances, etc. Read the text right after the 1st figure: "*one pole [...] is formed by the* **ideal** *integrator*". So they are telling you that the transfer function is ideal, then they proceed to tell you that nothing is ideal, so there will be limitations. And the effect is what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that the error amplifier is the non-ideal integrator, they are one and the same. If you were to consider an ideal integrator and then place a resistor in parallel with the feedback capacitor, the transfer function is that of a low pass filter with the closed loop pole at wp = 1/(Rfb.Cfb). Reducing the size of that parallel feedback resistor reduces the dc gain and the closed loop pole moves up in frequency.